# Styling select borders in IE changes the arrow button

Tags: css, internet-explorer, windows-xp

Our website has border styles on select boxes and text inputs to make them look like they would in the windows XP style on windows. This basically gives them a thin blue border rather than the grey bevelled one in windows classic. I have made no attept to change the style on the little down arrow button next to the selects. The CSS looks liek this:

```
border: 1px solid #7F9DB9;
```

The final effect that I am after is a blue border on all selects and text inputs, and selects should have the system default for the little dropdown arrow button.

This works fine in all non-IE browsers. And it works fine in IE 7. It even works fine in IE8 RC1 provided that the windows classic theme is being used. However in IE8 RC1 if you use the windows XP theme (blue curvy window headers) then IE8 RC1 continues to use the grey windows classic button.

This is how it renders in IE7: [alt text http://img128.imageshack.us/img128/1993/goodboxlr2.png](http://img128.imageshack.us/img128/1993/goodboxlr2.png)

This is how it renders in IE8 RC1: [alt text http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/8207/badboxvq8.png](http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/8207/badboxvq8.png)

Does anyone know how to get IE8 rendering it like IE7 does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer, you can't.

Styling drop-down lists, scrollbars and such will almost always leave you disappointed in some/most browsers.

I would just leave it to the theme to decide.

Comment: Agreed. The dropdown arrow, scrollbars, how the 'check' looks in a checkbox - these are beyond the CSS spec. Leaving them to the OS defaults, /whatever they may be/, is best.